# Inline Attachment Image Does Not Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**context**

when I try to do an inline image attachment with actionmailer it throws the following error

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

**code**

in mailer

```
  def inline_image(image_name)
    attachments.inline[image_name] = File.read())
  end

  def shared_user_email()
    inline_image(image_name_string)
    mail(to: email, subject: whatever)
  end
```

in template

```
  <%= image_tag attachments[image_name].url %>
```

in controller

```
UserMailer.delay.shared_user_email()
```

**tried**

Tried using a specific hash ([Rails attachments inline are not shown correctly in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356924/rails-attachments-inline-are-not-shown-correctly-in-gmail))

Tried setting the content_Id ([Rails mailer error with inline attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580578/rails-mailer-error-with-inline-attachment))

No dice.

Comment: You need to specify the absolute path of the file you're trying to read as a parameter in File.read().

Comment: This uses the DelayedJob gem?  Not all things that work eagerly will continue to work after queuing as a delayed job.  Does `UserMail.shared_user_email()` work from a rails console without the delay?  @rb512 's comment is very likely correct.  The `File.read()` returns `nil` after queuing.

Comment: If I take out delayedJob is works; thanks!

Comment: Gene if you put up the issue with delayed jobs as the solution I'll accept it. Your call.